# Trying to get another Website when the user want to open Facebook in the system Browser

Tags: android, android-webview

For this,I am using this Code,

```
try {

                                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
                                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                                StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
                                String line = "";
                                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
                                {

                                    if(line.contains("facebook.com"))
                                    {
                                        //Browser.addSearchUrl(getContentResolver(), "google");
                                        Log.i(Tag1,"ww"+ line);

                                        /*Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(startMain);*/
                                        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);

                                    }
                                  //log.;
                                }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I want to open Google when the user try to open Facebook in the system browser.
For this ,I am reading Logcat and get www.facebook.com.

Comment: what exactly you want? and when can you elobrate it please?

Comment: I want to block Facebook in system browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190006/i-am-trying-to-block-facebook-on-system-browser    Exact Question